# Does $a_n = \frac{n}{n+\sqrt{n}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the following sequence converge or diverge?
$$
a_n = \frac{n}{n+\sqrt{n}}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%2F%28n%2Bsqrt+%28n%29%29

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are trying to get others to do your homework. Also, type your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If you show effort your questions will be better received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint only. Divide top and bottom by $n$. Let $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Oh I see! I didn't approach it that way! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find out why you can write $a_n=\frac{1} {1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} \overset{n\to\infty} {\to} 1 $

Answer (score 1):

Consider that

$$a_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+1}$$

And

$$\bigg|\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+1}-1\bigg|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{n+\sqrt n} = 1$